# How to build a nested object from 2 SQLite tables?

Tags: sql, json, sqlite, join, group-by

Having not a SQLite background, I'm struggling building a "simple" SQLite query.
Considering the simplified schema below:

```
** Table: EVENTS **
id   content
1    abc
2    xyz

** Table: TIMESLOTS **
id   start     end
1    05-2022   06-2022
1    10-2022   12-2022
2   .......  .......
```

I'd like to build object like this on:

```
{
  id: 1,
  content: abc,
  timeslots:
    [
     {start: 05-2022, end: 06-2022},
     {start: 10-2022, end: 12-2022},
     ...
    ]
},
...
```

I'am able to do it in **2** queries and then build the object programaticaly (easy!)

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = 1
SELECT * FROM timeslots WHERE id = 1
```

But I'd like to make it in **1** to leverage DB power, not JS.
Is there a simple way to do it? `JOIN` doesn't seem to allow me building this kind of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the tables, aggregate by `id` and use [SQLite's JSON functions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) to build the json object:

```
SELECT json_object(
         'id', e.id,
         'content', e.content,
         'timeslots', json_group_array(
                        json_object(
                          'start', t.start,
                          'end', t.end
                        )
                      )
       ) col
FROM events e INNER JOIN timeslots t
ON t.id = e.id
-- WHERE e.id = ?
GROUP BY e.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/T_3mYuHl).

Comment: Thanks. Not as easy as I thought but It fully works. Two small questions: what is the 'col' thing ? + When I uncomment WHERE condition, it seems to break: https://dbfiddle.uk/pj7ExUtA ?

Comment: @charnould (1) `col` is the alias of the returned column, (2) it breaks because I misplaced the WHERE clause. See my edited answer.

Comment: First thks. I've added a reverse and linked question. If you have some clue (you seem to be a very active and knowledgeable DB StackOverflow user!)

Comment: @charnould don't add a new question to the current one because: (1) you invalidate any existing answers and (2)more than 1 questions in the same post is a reason for closure of the question as "Needs more focus". If you have a new requirement you should ask a new question.

Comment: I've reversed the edit and I'm writing a new question.