# How to build a SQLite query with a WHERE clause inside a JSON-array-of-objects-column?

Tags: json, sqlite

Linked to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76130858/how-to-build-a-nested-object-from-2-sqlite-tables/76130990), I try to build a SQLite high-performance* query on a JSON-column.
Considering a DB with this schema **(pseudo-code)**:

```
** Table **
id   content  json
1    abc      [{start: some-unix-ts, end: some-unix-ts},{start: some-unix-ts, end: some-unix-ts}, between 1 to 1K+ items]
2    xyz      ...
```

Is it possible to write a query fetching all events where content = `xyz` AND where there is at least one occurrence in the future, or between two timestamps.
In pseudo-code:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE content = xyz AND start > some-unix-ts
```

*) By high-performance I mean (having no SQL background): if on a theoretically huge DB it is not efficient at all, let me now!

Comment: SQLite was designed for convenience, not performance, and it sucks for huge databases.  If you need a high-performance solution for large datasets, then you need to use a real database server, like MySQL or Postgres.  They aren't that much more difficult to set up then SQLite.

Comment: Further, the base SQLite doesn't support JSON columns.  It does not have a full type system -- it stores everything strings (including numbers).  There is a JSON extension available, but because it's not core, it's never going to be super fast.

Comment: If you a) have one row per element of those json arrays, b) use a [date format understood by SQLite](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype) like a unix timestamp or iso-8601 string that naturally sorts, you'll have a better time.

Comment: @TimRoberts SQLite supports types besides strings and stores numeric types as numbers not strings (depending on the table definition, see https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_affinity ). And the json functions are enabled by default these days (and was always a core part of SQLite). Not that OP should be storing their data in json arrays here.

Comment: Your JSON objects are malformed for SQLite because both paths and values are unquoted, Also the values are in the non-comparable format MM-YYYY. Instead you should use YYYY-MM if you really care about performance since the use of string functions to transform the current format to a comparable one in the WHERE clause will cause much worse performance. But even if you make these changes I don't believe that a high-performance query is feasible for a large database.

Comment: @forpas : I've updated my question (dates are indeed on timestamp format + it's of course a well-formated Json)

Comment: If you have multiple `start` values for a given `id`, do you want them all or just one to be `> some-unix-ts`?

Comment: And is your expected output just the `start` values which are `> some-unix-ts` or the entire entry for that `id`?

Comment: @Nick I've added some details. The query should return `events` where - for example - there is at least one occurrence in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want using [`json_each`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach) to split out the timeslot values in the `json` column and then compare them with the time you are interested in. For example (using an expanded dbfiddle from the answer to your prior question):

```sql
SELECT ev.id, ev.content, json_each.value
FROM ev, json_each(ev.json)
WHERE ev.content = 'xyz' 
  AND json_each.value->>'$.start' > '2022-07'
```

Output:

```
id  content value
2   xyz     {"start":"2022-11","end":"2022-12"}
3   xyz     {"start":"2022-09","end":"2022-10"}
```

However this will not be particularly performant. It would be much better to go back to your original tables and query them instead:

```sql
SELECT e.*, t.start, t.end
FROM events e
JOIN timeslots t ON t.id = e.id
WHERE e.content = 'xyz' AND t.start > '2022-07'
```

Output:

```
id  content start   end
2   xyz     2022-11 2022-12
3   xyz     2022-09 2022-10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tl8I-24y)

You will need to replace the `start` comparisons with whatever is appropriate for your actual timeslot data.

Comment: @charnould did this answer your question? If not, can you provide more information to help answer it?

Comment: Thanks. I denormalize my data: (i) keep a `timeslots`column into `events` as a JSON to simplify request API for some people and (ii) keep a `timeslots` table to get performant query.

Comment: @charnould sounds like the perfect balance of size/performance.